# Turn off telemetry in SQL Server install config file

Tags: sql-server, configuration, installation, sql-server-2017

I'm creating a SQL Server 2017 Image Completion config file, and the automatically generated one has a bunch of stuff about "telemetry". I clicked no to the prompts, but it still put several user accounts in the config file, yet no true/false option for the telemetry itself. Here are the user accounts it included in the config file:

> ; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
>
> SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY"
>
> ; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription
>
> SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
>
> ; ASTelemetryStartupConfigDescription
>
> ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
>
> ; ASTelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
>
> ASTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SSASTELEMETRY"
>
> ; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
>
> ISTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY140"
>
> ; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription
>
> ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

I suppose I could change the startup type to manual, but I would rather just remove all this garbage. Any idea how to turn this off via config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, the only way to disable telemetry is to change the registry keys later. There is no actual harm to having those accounts, I don't think.

Comment: There is always harm in having unused accounts ...